# How to connect/export the database in Magento DevBox (docker container)?

Tags: devbox-beta

I've just setup the DevBox (Beta) with an install of Magento 2 by running through their wizard and executing the install script.

Everything appears to have worked fine, but I can't figure out any method to connect to and export the database.

No instructions on how to do this are given in the official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/docker/docker-over.html

I want to be able to export my dev database so I can import into my production instance. There must be some way to do this, or developing in DevBox would make no sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                         NAMES
3032464e8fd9        magento/magento2devbox-web:latest   "/usr/local/bin/en..."   About an hour ago   Up 54 minutes       5000/tcp, 9000/tcp, 44100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32770->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32769->80/tcp   magento2devbox_web_7299181703f96e251f8ade2bbb8a1763
835e5e466881        mysql:5.6                           "docker-entrypoint..."   About an hour ago   Up 54 minutes       0.0.0.0:32768->3306/tcp                                                       magento2devbox_db_7299181703f96e251f8ade2bbb8a1763
```

Under the mysql:5.6 image, you see 0.0.0.0:32768->3306/tcp.

This means that you can use a MySQL client like [Sequel Pro](https://www.sequelpro.com/) or [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to connect:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1

Username: root 

Password: root

Port: 32768
```

> I'm not sure if the port is constant.

But you can always check with `docker ps`. In [the guide you linked](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/docker/docker-over.html), it looks like there are instructions to set up a static port so that connecting with PHPStorm is less burdensome. I assume this process generalizes to the MySQL container.

> The default **username:password** is **root:root**.

You can confirm this:

```
[local]$ docker exec --user=magento2 -it magento2devbox_web_12345678 /bin/bash
[magento2]$ cd magento2
[magento2]$ cat app/etc/env.php
```

Inside you will see the database connection credentials.

Comment: appears to work fine in Sequel Pro, thanks

Comment: by the way... by default the database name is "magento2" and that's the only other credential required

Answer (score 1):

You can also go in directly to the container's mysql command line like so:

```
docker-compose exec db mysql -u root -p
```

(when prompted, the passwored is `root`)

This assumes the default DevBox settings with the mysql container called `db` and the username and password both as `root`.